# Using ServiceStack AutoQuery feature causes Autogeneration of WSDL failed error

Tags: servicestack

When I enable the AutoQuery feature in ServiceStack I get an `Autogeneration of WSDL failed` error.

The following exception is shown:

```cs
System.Runtime.Serialization.InvalidDataContractException: 
Type 'ServiceStack.QueryResponse`1[T]' cannot be exported as a schema type because it is an open generic type. 
You can only export a generic type if all its generic parameter types are actual types.
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSet.EnsureTypeNotGeneric(Type type)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XsdDataContractExporter.Export(ICollection`1 types)
   at ServiceStack.XsdUtils.GetXmlSchemaSet(ICollection`1 operationTypes)
   at ServiceStack.Metadata.XsdGenerator.ToString()
   at ServiceStack.Metadata.WsdlMetadataHandlerBase.GetWsdlTemplate(XsdMetadata operations, String baseUri, Boolean optimizeForFlash, String rawUrl, String serviceName)
   at ServiceStack.Metadata.WsdlMetadataHandlerBase.Execute(IRequest httpReq, IResponse httpRes)
```

It appears that the `QueryResponse` type returned used by AutoQuery is a generic type.

Request Object:

```cs
[Route("/Data/ApplicationLog")]
public class AutoQueryApplicationLog : QueryBase<ApplicationLog>
{
    public long[] Id { get; set; }
    public string[] LogLevel { get; set; }
    public string[] Source { get; set; }
    public string[] Message { get; set; }
    public string[] Host { get; set; }
    public string[] Type { get; set; }
    public string[] Logger { get; set; }
    public string[] CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CreatedDateGreaterThanOrEqualTo { get; set; }
}
```

Response Object:

```
[DataContract(Name = "ApplicationLog", Namespace = "http://Rx30.Services.aa.is/types")]
public class ApplicationLog
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    [AutoIncrement]
    [DataMember]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string LogLevel { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Source { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Message { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string StackTrace { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Host { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Logger { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
}
```

Is there a way to correct this error?

Comment: Can you also add your Request / Response DTO's that use AutoQuery which causes this error?

Comment: I have added the Request and Response DTO's

Answer (score 1):

This should be now [fixed with this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/db75c651cc2c58300d788752f85e4e0321e74c52) that will be in the **v4.0.24+** release of ServiceStack that's [now available on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet).